# Error en añadir descuentos individuales en cada item

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax, mysqli

Tengo los siguientes campos `input` que me permite crear o actualizar descuentos individuales:

```
<div class="bsk-dto">
    <input type="text" name="dtoupdate[3][Normal][Normal][Normal][1][%]" value="3" class="dto" autocomplete="off" data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="float">
</div>
<div class="bsk-dto">
    <input type="text" name="dtoupdate[6][Normal][Normal][Normal][1][%]" value="1" class="dto" autocomplete="off" data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="float">
</div>
<div class="bsk-dto">
    <input type="text" name="dtoupdate[10][Normal][Normal][Normal][1][%]" value="0" class="dto" autocomplete="off" data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="float">
</div>
```

Cabe mencionar que todos esos `input` están en la misma página, por lo tanto, he intentado que `ajax` reciba solo información del campo `input` que es manipulado, por lo consiguiente he intentado lo siguiente:

```
var formData = [];
formData.push(this.value);
var formData = $(this).serializeArray();

console.log(formData);
```

Y de la siguiente manera:

```
const field = {};
field[this.name] = this.value;
console.log(field);
```

Pese que ambos procedimientos he utilizado `this` me genera este problema:

[image]

Como se puede apreciar si manipulo uno de los campos `input` se modifica o se actualizan los demás y lo que realmente deseo es que solo se modifique o se actualice los datos de solo ese campo `input` que estoy manipulando.

Este es mi código completo de ajax:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('input', '.dto', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $this = $(this);
        /*const field = {};
        field[this.name] = this.value;
        console.log(field);
        */
        var formData = [];
        formData.push(this.value);
        var formData = $(this).serializeArray();

        console.log(formData);

        var url = "updsc_cart.ini.php";

       //data: field,
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            let res = JSON.parse(data);
            if(res.status){
                $('.alert-success').fadeIn();
                $('.alert-success').html(res.message).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
            } else {
                $('.alert-danger').fadeIn();
                $('.alert-danger').html(res.message).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
            }
        })
        .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
        })
    });
});
```

Trato de obtener la información desde el momento que se manipula el campo `input`: `$(document).on('input', '.dto', function(e)` ¿Que hace falta para que el código ajax funcione correctamente en la manipulación de campo `input` individualmente sin que afecte a los demás `input` al manipular?

---

La actualización se esta guardando correctamente, para verificar dicha información de la siguiente linea:

```
$item_dto = (isset($_SESSION['item_dto']) && is_array($_SESSION['item_dto'])) ? $_SESSION['item_dto'] : array();
```

Voy a imprimir realizando `print_r($item_dto)` teniendo la siguiente información:

```
Array
(
    [2192] => Array
        (
            [Normal] => Array
                (
                    [Normal] => Array
                        (
                            [Normal] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [%] => 0
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [2190] => Array
        (
            [Normal] => Array
                (
                    [Normal] => Array
                        (
                            [Normal] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [%] => 10
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
1
```

El problema es el `foreach` que esta dentro del ciclo `while`:

```
$items = (isset($_SESSION['cart']) && is_array($_SESSION['cart'])) ? $_SESSION['cart'] : array();
$item_dto = (isset($_SESSION['item_dto']) && is_array($_SESSION['item_dto'])) ? $_SESSION['item_dto'] : array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) {

    $id_article = $outcome['id_product'];
    $dto_op = NULL;
    $dto = NULL;

    //$dto_op: Obtener el tipo de descuento % o $ y $dto: el valor total del descuento
    foreach($item_dto[$outcome['id_product']] as $color => $sizes){
        foreach($sizes as $size => $models){
            foreach($models as $model => $quantities) {
                foreach($quantities as $quantity => $dto_ops) {
                    foreach($dto_ops as $dto_op => $dto) {
                        //$dto_op .= $dto_op;
                        $dto_item += $dto;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    foreach($items[$outcome['id_product']] as $color => $sizes){
        foreach($sizes as $size => $models){
            foreach($models as $model => $quantity) {

                echo $outcome['cover_product'] . $outcome['title_product'] . $outcome['price'] . $dto_item .  $outcome['iva'];

            }
        }
    }
}
$stmt->close();
```

Al imprimir esta variable `$dto_item` me imprime `10` para ambos `input` en el `print_r` vemos que esta un valor de `[%] => 0` y otro de `[%] => 10` esa variable debería imprimir una de `0` y otra de `10` en el `input`:

```
... value="<?php echo $dto_item; ?>"
```

Comment: @masterguru Amigo he actualizado la pregunta, realmente no hace falta mencionar la base de datos ya que la tabla `tbl_products` solo tiene información básica como `id_product, title_product, price, iva` sin embargo he agregado la forma de como se agregan los productos al carro de compra todo se procesa con el id del producto y los datos adicionales.

Comment: @masterguru Yo creo que todo esto lo debo procesar así `$_SESSION['cart'][$id_article][$color][$size][$NUEVAVARIABLEDEDESCUENTO] = intval($quantity);` agregar una nueva variable a la sesión del carrito

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140660/discussion-between-otto-and-masterguru).

Comment: @masterguru cada producto se guarda en `session` los siguientes datos: *el id del producto, modelo, talla, color y cantidad* toda esa información se guarda en variables diseñando la estructura de la SESSION: `$_SESSION['cart'][$itemId][$item_color][$item_size][$item_model] = $qty;` lo mismos datos de ese producto lo guardo en una nueva SESSION, solo que aquí agrego dos detalles más el tipo de descuento que va ser ya sea en porcentajes `%` o descuento fijo `$` y el valor que se va aplicar descuento quedando así el código:

Comment: @A.Cedano `$_SESSION['item_dto'][$itemId][$item_color][$item_size][$item_model][$qty][$item_dto_op] = $item_dto;` ahora ya tengo dos sesiones la misma que estoy comprobando dentro del `while` ya que si pueden apreciar en ambos `foreach` se esta pasando el id del producto `foreach($item_dto[$outcome['id_product']] as...` y `foreach($items[$outcome['id_product']] as...`

Comment: @A.Cedano el problema es que al imprimir los datos del `foreach` de la sesión de descuento individual `$_SESSION['item_dto']...` sus datos se están repitiendo al imprimirlos `$dto_item` y otros casos repitiendo por cada `item` agregado al carrito de compra.

Comment: Otto no puede seguir el hilo a todo el debate en el chat por falta de tiempo. Sospecho que hay algún problema de diseño en todo esto y quizá debas replanteartelo. El que sea XML, base de datos, JSON, no importa. El modelo de datos es el modelo de datos y si está bien hecho puede acoplarse con facilidad a todo. Realmente XML, BD, JSON o quien sea, son formas de representar un modelo de datos. De hecho, partiendo de uno, puedes pasar a otro con los mismos resultados, lo único que cambiará será la forma de leer los datos.

Comment: @Otto Gracias por la explicación, pero eso ya lo entendí perfectamente cuando me lo explicastes la primera vez y a través de tus preguntas.  Mi principal duda y curiosidad era otra pero no voy a insistir en preguntartelo de nuevo. Te agradezco el intento por explicarlo (aunque no era lo que te pedia) y me quedo con que me falta mucho contexto y código para entender lo sucedido en la pregunta que has borrado, pero que no es magia :-)  Saludos!!

Comment: En cuanto a esta pregunta en sí misma, quizá se puede recurrir a un moderador para que quite la recompensa, pues creo que el problema existe a otro nivel y mientras no resuelvas eso, serás esclavo del código. El problema, cuando hay un problema a otro nivel, es que uno intenta resolver ese problema donde no debe resolverse, llevando a veces a programas hipercomplicados... hasta que algo evoluciona y tienes que volver a ese dolor de cabeza de código, para seguir resolviendo algo en el sitio equivocado... OJO: es sólo una intuición mía, no tengo por qué tener razón.

Comment: @A.Cedano El problema es que se van muy lejos, es innecesario decirles si es base de datos o xml, si estoy siendo claro que los datos los guardo en mediante SESSION, el único problema es pasarle los datos de `%` y el valor al otro `foreach` que es el encargado de imprimir los productos en el carrito de compras, no entiendo porque complicarnos tanto.

Comment: @masterguru El problema es que se van muy lejos, es innecesario decirles si es base de datos o xml, si estoy siendo claro que los datos los guardo en mediante SESSION, el único problema es pasarle los datos de `%` y el valor al otro `foreach` que es el encargado de imprimir los productos en el carrito de compras, no entiendo porque complicarnos tanto. Ya voy a ver cómo lo arreglo, ya he avanzado bastante como para dejarlo todo allí.

Comment: Otto es que a veces hay que ir más lejos. Esto no debería ser tan complicado realmente, si lo es, porque hay un problema en otra parte, y es eso lo que lo hace complicado. Si hay un error en el modelo de datos por ejemplo, tarde o temprano tendrás que corregir ese error, sea porque el programa empieza a ralentizarse, sea porque surge una nueva necesidad que te pone en un callejón sin salida. Repito que no tengo por qué tener razón, es sólo una intuición y puede que esté exagerando.

Comment: @A.Cedano Estoy de acuerdo siempre en cuando se vincule base de datos, en este caso simplemente se estaban guardando sessiones la misma que necesitaba poder manipular correctamente, ya lo solucione. En el primer `foreach` estaba realizando algo tipo concatenación, tenía un concepto equivocado que cuando necesitas sacar información de un `bucle` debes concatenar esas variables, pero intenté imprimir esos datos fuera del `foreach` y funcionó, imagínate tener que ir analizar tantas cosas que se discutió por comentarios, en si , yo mismo solucioné todo, ya di la recompensa para cerrar el hilo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes

**1) El javascript**

Es muy parecido a lo que tú tienes, solo que yo creo un form e introduzco una clonación del input que generó el evento.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('input', '.dto', function (e) {
        let form = document.createElement("form");
        form.append(this.cloneNode());
        EnviarData(form,null,this);
    });
});

function guardar() {
    event.preventDefault();
    EnviarData(event.target, event.submitter.getAttribute('formaction'));
    return false;
}

function EnviarData(form, action,input) {
    let url = "pagina.php";
    if (action) {
        url=url + "?action=" + action
    }
            
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url ,
        data: $(form).serialize(),
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        //cosas aca
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        //avisos aca
    });
}
```

**2) El PHP**

Esta es la parte complicada, porque no se entiende la lógica que estas usando. Yo lo que veo en el HTML es que pones los siguientes nombres a los inputs

dtoupdate[3][Normal][Normal][Normal][1][%]

Y de esto entiendo que:

- 3 => Es una id, pero creo que no es la id real
- Normal (1) => Color
- Normal (2) => Size
- Normal (3) => Model
- 1 => Cantidad
- % => Tipo de descuento

Hasta aca creo no haberme equivocado, pero lo que me confunde son los while/for que tu pones en tu código.

Porque si estas enviando 1 solo dato para que aplique un update al descuento, porque habrías de iterar?? (es un solo dato)

Porque para obtener los valores que enviaste puedes hacer "simplemente" eso:

```
$itemID = array_keys($_POST['dtoupdate'])[0];
$color = array_keys($_POST['dtoupdate'][$itemID])[0];
$size = array_keys($_POST['dtoupdate'][$itemID][$color])[0];
$model = array_keys($_POST['dtoupdate'][$itemID][$color][$size])[0];
$quantity = array_keys($_POST['dtoupdate'][$itemID][$color][$size][$model])[0];
$tipo_descuento = array_keys($_POST['dtoupdate'][$itemID][$color][$size][$model][$quantity])[0];
$descuento = $_POST['dtoupdate'][$itemID][$size][$model][$color][$quantity][$tipo_descuento];

//Si entendí tu código esto debería setear el descuento
$item_dto[$outcome[$itemID]][$size][$model][$color][$quantity][$tipo_descuento] = $descuento;
```

Y ya con estos datos puedes operar en tus otras estructuras como si un diccionarios se tratasen, porque de hecho lo son.