# ¿Cómo añadir producto desde la paginación al carro de la compra usando ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax, mysqli

Este es mi archivo PHP, que me permite agregar productos a la cesta:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST) OR isset($_POST['addCart'])) {
  $attributes = (
    isset($_POST['qtyupdate']) && is_array($_POST['qtyupdate'])
  ) ? $_POST['qtyupdate'] : array();

  $itemId = isset($_POST['itemId']) ? $_POST['itemId'] : "";
  $item_color = isset($_POST['color']) ? $_POST['color'] : "Normal";
  $item_size = isset($_POST['size']) ? $_POST['size'] : "Normal";
  $qty = isset($_POST['qty']) ? intval($_POST['qty']) : 1;

  if (
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and 
    isset($_POST['qtyupdate'])
  ) {
    foreach ($attributes as $id_article => $variations) {
      foreach($variations as $color => $sizes) {
        foreach($sizes as $size => $quantity) {
          if ($quantity <= 0) {
            echo json_encode([
              'status' => FALSE, 
              'message' => "<strong>Error no hemos podido actualizar su producto.</strong>"
            ]);
            exit;
          } else {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$id_article][$color][$size] = intval($quantity);
            echo json_encode([
              'status'=> TRUE,
              'message'=>"<strong>Se ha actualizado su producto.</strong>"
            ]);
            exit;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (is_numeric($itemId)) {
    $_SESSION['cart'][$itemId][$item_color][$item_size] = $qty;
    echo json_encode([
      'status' => TRUE,
      'message' => "<strong>El producto ha sido añadido a su carrito.</strong>"
    ]);
    exit;
  }
}
```

Este es mi código `ajax`, funciona bien cuando el botón añadir esta en una pagina individual y si es el único botón que existe:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.close', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.alert-success').hide();
    $('.alert-danger').hide();
  });
  var frm = $('#frmCart');
  frm.submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = frm.serialize();
    formData += '&' + $('#addCart').attr('name') + 
      '=' + $('#addCart').attr('value');

    var url = "addItem_cart.ini.php";
    $.ajax({
      type: frm.attr('method'),
      url: url,
      data: formData,
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      let res = JSON.parse(data);
      if(res.status){
        $("#wrapp-basket").load(" #wrapp-basket").fadeIn();
        $("#qty").load(" #qty").fadeIn();
        $('.alert-success').fadeIn();
        $('.alert-success').html(res.message).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
        $(".alert-success").append(
          "<button class='close' type='button'><span aria-hidden='true'>x</span></button>"
        );
      } else {
        $('.alert-danger').fadeIn();
        $('.alert-danger').html(res.message).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
        $(".alert-danger").append(
          "<button class='close' type='button'><span aria-hidden='true'>x</span></button>"
        );
      }
    })
    .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
      alert("Ajax Request fail");
      //$('.warning').fadeIn();
      //$('.warning').html(textStatus).delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
      //console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
      //console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus );
    })
  });
});
```

El problema es cuando tengo varios botones de añadir productos en este caso desde un paginador, el botón no funciona o más bien el `ajax` deja de funcionar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es el `HTML` de los botones cuando están en la paginación:

```
<form><div class="shipping">
  <label></label>
  <em>$13,00</em>
  <input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="2">
  <input type="submit" id="addCart" class="addCart buy"
    name="addCart" value="Añadir a la cesta" formnovalidate="">
</div></form>
<form><div class="shipping">
  <label></label>
  <em>$8,00</em>
  <input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="2">
  <input type="submit" id="addCart" class="addCart buy"
    name="addCart" value="Añadir a la cesta" formnovalidate="">
</div></form>
<form><div class="shipping">
  <label></label>
  <em>$10,00</em>
  <input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="2">
  <input type="submit" id="addCart" class="addCart buy"
    name="addCart" value="Añadir a la cesta" formnovalidate="">
</div></form>
```

El botón de añadir esta dentro de un `form` es porque envió otros datos adicionales de otros campos `input, select, radio`

Como le puede decir a `ajax` o `jquery` que datos debe tomar y que funcione al presionar el botón añadir teniendo en cuenta que todos tiene el mismo nombre: `id="addCart" class="addCart buy"` ya que se encuentra listado en una paginación.

Comment: para "respuesta canónica" agrega el php donde imprimis el html con `id` duplicados así limpiamos eso primero y el resto sale mas simple

Comment: @aloMalbarez  Demasiado código amigo, la generación del `HTML` es sencillo de eliminar, solo basta con cambiar en el ciclo, de esto `<input type="submit" id="addCart" class="addCart buy"` puede quedar así sin problemas `<input type="submit" class="addCart buy"` ya descartando problemas con PHP, el problema va en el ajax, creo que toca pasarle algo así como un `$(this).parent().attr('id');` para que `ajax` pueda saber que form enviar

Comment: no hace falta que lo pongas completo, es que si duplicas id en algun momento o con algun navegador va a dar problemas, si necesitas que las cosas tengan id los hacemos dinamico, y el jquery lo ajustamos para ids dinamicos; sino es reemplazar por clases. pero para que sea canonico debe ser una solucion general y no un parche a una situacion particular

Comment: @aloMalbarez Amigo de esa manera imprimo o género el HTML: `while($stmt->fetch()){ echo '<form><div class="shipping">
  <label></label>
  <em>$'.$price.'</em>
  <input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="'.$id_product.'">
  <input type="submit" id="addCart" class="addCart buy"
    name="addCart" value="Añadir a la cesta" formnovalidate="">
</div></form>';`

Answer (score 1):

1. Lo primero es separar el submit en una función aparte, le llamaré "guardar()"

```
function guardar() {
    event.preventDefault();
    EnviarData(event.target, event.submitter.getAttribute('formaction'));
    return false;
}
function EnviarData(form, action,input) {
    let url = "pagina.php";
    if (action) {
        url=url + "?action=" + action
    }
            
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url ,
        data: $(form).serialize(),
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        //cosas aca
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        //avisos aca
    });
}
```

2. Ahora todos tus forms debe setear el evento submit y opcionalmente el atributo formaction en el botón

```
<form onsubmit="guardar()" >
        <div class="shipping">
            <label></label>
            <em>$13,00</em>
            <input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="2" />
            <input type="submit" id="addCart" class="addCart buy" formaction="addCart" formnovalidate="" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

El atributo formaction indicará al PHP que acción tomar en el submit. Lo recuperas con $_GET["action"]. En el ejemplo de arriba sería "addCart". Con esto tú puedes hacer un if o un switch, para filtrar distintas cosas (acciones)  que envías al mismo PHP, como podria ser remove, update, etc

3. como hacer el envió fuera del form

Por ejemplo este caso:

```
<form onsubmit="guardar()" id="ajaxData">
  //cosas
</form>
<input type="submit" class="addCart buy" form="ajaxData" formaction="remove" />
```

En este caso solo es necesario ocupar el atributo form en el `ìnput submit` con el id del formulario (ajaxData)

Otro caso, ahora utilizando un anchor () en vez de un input submit

```
<a id="gateway" data-ref="#" class="continue-checkout center" onclick="EnviarData(ajaxData,'alguna cosa')">Solo Guardar</a>
```

Acá ocupamos directamente la función EnviarData, pasando el formulario como primer argumento y opcionalmente la acción como segundo argumento. También es posible enviar un tercer argumento que es un elemento el cual podría ser el mismo botón (poniendo this),

Comment: Lo voy a revisar, no es más útil usar algo como `$(this).parent().attr('id');` para que `ajax` pueda saber que form enviar ?

Comment: @Otto Ese código podría servir si el evento estuviera en el botón (debería ser $(this).parent().parent()), ahí subes buscando al padre que es un form. Pero en este caso el evento está en el mismo form, por lo que `this` es el form. Como algunas veces hay problemas de `scope` yo prefiero usar event.target que retorna el elemento que gatilló el evento. y además $(event.target) no tiene que recorrer el dom buscando el elemento, por lo que es más eficiente.

Comment: Entiendo, se ve interesante de esa manera, quizás se puede enviar un parámetro o dato adicional en un solo `form` en dónde tengo dos botones fuera del `form` me gustaría que uno de ellos tenga una acción diferente por ejemplo uno de esos botones que sea guardar y el otro que sea enviar. La pregunta sale del tema pero quisiera saber si es posible y aprovechar el planteamiento de su respuesta para poder reutilizar está alternativa de solución en otros casos o saber cómo aprovechar estás soluciones.

Comment: @Otto Es posible con un pequeño ajuste. También es posible realizar submit fuera del form, existe el atributo `form` que le indica al botón cual form haga submit (aunque esté afuera). Pero deberías dar más detalle para una respuesta concreta

Comment: Aquí te dejo un copilador con más detalles en el código comentado https://jsfiddle.net/dhktoLm3/1/

Comment: @Otto Ok, mañana lo reviso bien. Pero en teoría si le agregas <form id="ajaxData"  onsubmit="guardar()" debería funcionar igual. Me queda la duda si pasa lo mismo usando JQuery, pero como te decía mañana lo pruebo y te respondo

Comment: De funcionar quizás funcione pero si deseo saber cómo hacerle llegar a php que botón se presionó

Comment: @Otto Ahhhhhhh por fin entendí tu problemática. Para eso ponías  formData += '&' + $('#addCart').attr('name') + 
      '=' + $('#addCart').attr('value'); Déjame darle una vuelta y te aviso

Comment: La respuesta que me has dado está bien amigo, lo que te comento es otro tema fuera de la pregunta cómo te mencioné si me gustaría saber ese pequeño detalle para poder reutilizar este código en otras cosas

Comment: y que no solo quede para el tema añadir productos, pero revísalo mañana con calma

Comment: @Otto Si la respuesta está bien, porque no la has marcado como aceptada??? me queda esa duda

Comment: He estado peleando con la otra pregunta que no he probado la solución, ya veo ahora.

Comment: @Otto He actualizado la respuesta, para colocar los temas que hablamos ayer

Comment: Me he confundidos con los cambios que has realizado, los temas que tratamos era más que todo de como socarle provecho a los cambios que has realizado en mi código `ajax` de poder saber si se pueden enviar un dato diferente mediante el `subtmit` con esa función de `function guardar()` voy a probar esto pero lo otro importante no me funciona que es añadir los productos al carro desde una paginación, indico paginación es para ser énfasis que dicho `form` se repite múltiples veces por las cantidades de productos que se muestren y de tal manera no funciona: https://jsfiddle.net/c1mnq8ox/

Comment: @Otto El cambio fue mínimo, lo único que me falto agregar la función guardar (que ya la puse en la respuesta).   Pero es el mismo código que coloqué en otro respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/569082/301324 , lo hice así ya que me decías buscabas algo más genérico.  Por otro lado debería funcionar con paginación, porque no hago uso de addEventListener, entonces mientras el form tenga declarado el atributo onsubmit no debería haber problema