# ¿Cómo sumar la base imponible de los códigos repetidos dentro de un ciclo?

Tags: php

Cada producto puede tener diferente tipo de impuestos como `IVA` o sin impuestos, pero existe uno que es muy especial ya que este impuesto depende de algunos productos o fabricación que se identifica (`type_ice`) con un código sus categorías y se le asigna un porcentaje de impuesto el mismo que se va llamar `ICE`.

Por ejemplo tengo en la tabla `tbl_product` los siguientes productos:

| id_product | title_product | iva | type_ice | ice | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | title1 | 0 | 3110 | 5 | 20.00 |
| 2 | title2 | 12 | 3110 | 5 | 30.00 |
| 3 | title3 | 0 | 3120 | 10 | 40.00 |
| 4 | title4 | 12 | 3120 | 10 | 70.00 |
| 5 | title5 | 0 | 3120 | 5 | 45.00 |
| 6 | title6 | 0 | NULL | 0 | 25.00 |
| 7 | title6 | 12 | NULL | 0 | 35.00 |

Como no todo producto tiene impuesto `ICE` era necesario que solo se imprima valores o dato adicional solo los productos que tenga impuestos `ICE` fue sencillo, lo solucione de la siguiente manera:

```
if($outcome['type_ice'] == TRUE) {
   code...
}
```

Funciona muy bien cuando se hayan añadido productos que sean de códigos diferentes de la columna `type_ice` del impuesto `ICE`, por ejemplo se ha añadido los productos del `id` `1` y `4` esto me genera una parte del código `XML` valido:

```
        <totalImpuesto>
            <codigo>3</codigo>
            <codigoPorcentaje>3110</codigoPorcentaje>
            <baseImponible>20.00</baseImponible>
            <valor>1.00</valor>
        </totalImpuesto>
        <totalImpuesto>
            <codigo>3</codigo>
            <codigoPorcentaje>3120</codigoPorcentaje>
            <baseImponible>70.00</baseImponible>
            <valor>7.00</valor>
        </totalImpuesto>
```

Ahora nuevamente como ejemplo se agrega los productos con el `id` `1` y `2` esto me genera esta estructura `XML` no valida:

```
        <totalImpuesto>
            <codigo>3</codigo>
            <codigoPorcentaje>3110</codigoPorcentaje>
            <baseImponible>20.00</baseImponible>
            <valor>1.00</valor>
        </totalImpuesto>
        <totalImpuesto>
            <codigo>3</codigo>
            <codigoPorcentaje>3110</codigoPorcentaje>
            <baseImponible>30.00</baseImponible>
            <valor>1.50</valor>
        </totalImpuesto>
```

Es no valida ya que se debe contabilizar todo, cuando el impuesto sea del mismo código del `type_ice` por lo tanto el formato correcto que debe salir es este:

```
         <totalImpuesto>
            <codigo>3</codigo>
            <codigoPorcentaje>3110</codigoPorcentaje>
            <baseImponible>50.00</baseImponible>
            <valor>2.50</valor>
        </totalImpuesto>
```

Como se puede observar se sumo los precios del producto `20.00+30.00` y también cada uno de sus impuestos `1.00+2.50`.

¿Cómo puedo lograr lo mismo dentro de un ciclo?, si fueran datos por imprimir, hubiese sido fácil realizarlo desde la consulta, pero estos productos se agregan al carro de la compra y mediante el mismo se generan las estructuras `XML`

Este es mi código del problema:

```
foreach($items[$outcome['id_product']] as $color => $sizes){
    foreach($sizes as $size => $models){
        foreach($models as $model => $quantity) {
            if($outcome['type_ice'] == TRUE) {
                if($totalTaxICE > 0) {
                    $xmlTotalICE .= '<totalImpuesto>
                    <codigo>3</codigo>
                    <codigoPorcentaje>'.$outcome['type_ice'].'</codigoPorcentaje>
                    <baseImponible>'.number_format($totalICETaxBase, 2).'</baseImponible>
                    <valor>'.number_format($totalTaxICE,2).'</valor>
                    </totalImpuesto>';
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

La variable `$items` tiene información de la `SESSION` de los productos añadido al carro de la compra de la siguiente manera:

```
$items = (isset($_SESSION['cart']) && is_array($_SESSION['cart'])) ? $_SESSION['cart'] : array();
```

Ahora las variables como `$color, $size, $model` son datos adicionales del producto, para tener una mejor idea al imprimir la variable `$items` tenemos la siguiente salida:

```
Array
(
    [2192] => Array
        (
            [Normal] => Array
                (
                    [Normal] => Array
                        (
                            [Normal] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [%] => 0
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [2190] => Array
        (
            [Normal] => Array
                (
                    [Normal] => Array
                        (
                            [Normal] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [%] => 10
                                        
)

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
1
```

Cabe aclarar que si algunos productos no tienen color, talla y modelo se agrega un valor por default que es `Normal`

Cómo referencia adjunto una pregunta anterior:

- [Error en añadir descuentos individuales en cada item](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/567980/error-en-a%c3%b1adir-descuentos-individuales-en-cada-item)

Otras variables importantes que pueden cambiar el valor del precio:

```
//Precio con impuesto ICE
$taxICE = ($outcome['price'] / 100) * $outcome['ice'];
$UnitPrice = $outcome['price'] + $taxICE;

//Total por cantidad del mismo producto agregado al carro
$price = $UnitPrice * $quantity;

//Descuento individual de productos -> $dto
$disc = ($price / 100) * $dto;

//Precio del producto con descuento
$priceDisc = $price - $disc;

//Total del precio menos el descuento (dato para etiqueta XML sobre el ICE)
$discTaxICE = ($taxICE / 100) * $dto;
$SubTotalTaxICE = $taxICE - $discTaxICE;
```

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega la estructura de `$items` y el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el problema.

Comment: De otra forma la respuesta tal vez sería muy genérica y tendrías que adaptarla o tal vez una probable respuesta no cubra las necesidades detrás de la porción de código que muestras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr lo que deseas, lo más sencillo es crear un array para almacenar los valores del impuesto ICE y, si ya existe un valor para el mismo código de impuesto, sumar los valores de base imponible y valor.

Para hacer esto, puedes utilizar un array asociativo, donde la clave será el código de impuesto y el valor será un array con dos elementos: base imponible y valor. De esta forma, podrás acceder a cada impuesto de forma sencilla y sumar los valores directamente.
Un ejemplo de cómo podrías implementarlo:

```
$impuestos = array();

// Recorremos todos los productos
foreach ($productos as $producto) {
  if ($producto['type_ice'] !== NULL) {
    // Si el impuesto no existe en el array, lo agregamos
    if (!isset($impuestos[$producto['type_ice']])) {
      $impuestos[$producto['type_ice']] = array(
        'base_imponible' => $producto['price'],
        'valor' => $producto['price'] * $producto['ice'] / 100
      );
    } else {
      // Si ya existe, sumamos los valores
      $impuestos[$producto['type_ice']]['base_imponible'] += $producto['price'];
      $impuestos[$producto['type_ice']]['valor'] += $producto['price'] * $producto['ice'] / 100;
    }
  }
}

// Ahora podemos recorrer el array de impuestos y generar el código XML
foreach ($impuestos as $codigo => $impuesto) {
  echo '<totalImpuesto>';
  echo '<codigo>3</codigo>';
  echo '<codigoPorcentaje>' . $codigo . '</codigoPorcentaje>';
  echo '<baseImponible>' . $impuesto['base_imponible'] . '</baseImponible>';
  echo '<valor>' . $impuesto['valor'] . '</valor>';
  echo '</totalImpuesto>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Con el fin de no modificar mucho el código que tienes al momento, lo que podrías hacer es agrupar los elementos que han sido añadidos al carrito de compras antes de crear tu `XML` y ya que han sido agrupados entonces creas el `XML` tal como lo tienes hasta ahora.

**Nota:** Como puse en los comentarios, desconozco la estructura de `$items` y tomar el tiempo de generar un arreglo que se ajuste el código que muestras para crear el `XML` sería a ciegas por lo que redacto una respuesta genérica que tendrías que adaptar a tus necesidades.

El concepto es sencillo, vamos a crear un arreglo para agrupar los elementos según su "type_ice" y sumar tanto el precio, que sería simplemente "price", así como el impuesto correspondiente, que sería `("price" * ("ice"/100.0))`.

Utilizamos [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) para saber si una llave existe o no al crear el arreglo con los elementos agrupados.

Ejemplo completo:

```
// Variable que contiene la declaración de cada producto
$outcome = [
    'id_product' => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    'title_product' => ['', 'title1', 'title2', 'title3', 'title4', 'title5', 'title6', 'title7'],
    'iva' => [NULL, 0, 12, 0, 12, 0, 0, 12],
    'type_ice' => [NULL, 3110, 3110, 3120, 3120, 3120, NULL, NULL],
    'ice' => [NULL, 5, 5, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0],
    'price' => [NULL, 20.00, 30.00, 40.00, 70.00, 45.00, 25.00, 35.00]
    ];

// Variable que almacena los productos que han sido añadidos
$items = [1, 2, 4];

// Variable para agrupar los productos según su "type_ice"
$groupedItems = [];

foreach ($items as $item) {
    
    // Revisamos si la llave del "type_ice" del elemento existe
    if (isset($groupedItems[$outcome['type_ice'][$item]])) {
        // En caso de que exista se suma el precio "total_price" que contiene el precio acumulado (Suma acumulada)
        // De igual forma se suma el iva a "total_iva"
        $groupedItems[$outcome['type_ice'][$item]]['total_price'] += $outcome['price'][$item];
        $groupedItems[$outcome['type_ice'][$item]]['total_iva'] += ($outcome['price'][$item] * ($outcome['ice'][$item] / 100.0));
    }
    else {
        // En caso de que no exista determinada llave entonces se crea (Por eso no se utiliza el operador +=, únicamente =)
        $groupedItems[$outcome['type_ice'][$item]]['total_price'] = $outcome['price'][$item];
        $groupedItems[$outcome['type_ice'][$item]]['total_iva'] = ($outcome['price'][$item] * ($outcome['ice'][$item] / 100.0));
    }
}

var_dump($groupedItems);
```

Esto devuelve:

```
array(2) {
  [3110]=>
  array(2) {
    ["total_price"]=>
    float(50)
    ["total_iva"]=>
    float(2.5)
  }
  [3120]=>
  array(2) {
    ["total_price"]=>
    float(70)
    ["total_iva"]=>
    float(7)
  }
}
```

Después puedes utilizar este nuevo arreglo con los elementos agrupados (Claro, adaptado según la estructura que tenga `$items` en tu código) en el código que mostraste para generar el `XML`.

Comment: Amigo, actualice la pregunta con más información, ahora verificó lo argumentado en su respuesta, gracias

Comment: De igual forma yo creo que para no afectar el código que tienes hasta ahora lo mejor sería agregar un arreglo intermedio para crear los grupos en base a `type_ice`, de esa forma no tendrías que reescribir la parte del `XML` que ya has comprobado que funciona.

Comment: Aún no entiendo en sí, en donde debo agregar esto `$xmlTotalICE .= '<totalImpuesto>` que es lo que genera el `XML`, debo agregarlo dentro de `if (isset($groupedItems[$outcome['type_ice'][$item]])) {`  pero veo que la variable `$groupedItems` agrupa todo los datos, no esta datos individuales para irlos agregando a la variable que genera el `XML` -> ``$xmlTotalICE .=  ..................`

Comment: Lo que intento decir es que crees un `foreach` antes del que ya tienes donde generas el `XML`. Este nuevo `foreach` va a agrupar los productos de acuerdo a su `type_ice` en la variable `$groupedItems` y entonces `$groupedItems` lo utilizas en el `foreach` que ya tienes para generar el `XML` de esa forma no tienes que modificar tanto lo que ya te funciona.

Comment: No logro comprender aún, pero si es lo que pienso esto no me va resultar fácil ya que el `foreach` actual no solo funciona para esta parte de dicho `XML` tengo más datos pero voy a intentar a ver que problema da.

Comment: Cree un [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141428/sumar-base-imponible) para platicarlo, por favor entra